# How to modify the behavior of one method on a javascript class when another method is called?

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js

I created a class on javascript using the p5.js package and I would like to know how I could modify the inner properties of a method with another method belonging to the same class.

So I basically created a class called bubble and those bubble(ellipse) move randomly in my canvas and bounce on the edge, this no problem. However I would like that, when I click on a bubble it transforms itself in a rectangle.

Please find the code after:

```
let bubbles = [];

// declare the  Bubbles array at the top.

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) // will create  i number of them.
  {
    let x = 10 + i / 20; // for the radisu of the ellipse
    bubbles[i] = new Bubble(random(0, 600), random(0, 400), 40, i);
  }
  // to create the elements; specify the arguments there. to create new arguments, goes in the constructor.
  // it is not mandatory to create the object here, you can also do it when the mouse is pressed=> see below

}

function mousePressed() {
  for (let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    bubbles[i].clicked(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 40);
  for (let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) { // i < bubbles.length , so when we create buble in setup they are all displayed . 
    bubbles[i].move();
    bubbles[i].show();
    bubbles[i].edge();
  }
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, r, col) {
    this.x = x; // inside a class, "this" is a refercence to the current object
    this.y = y; // those are the data used for the creation of the bubble.
    this.r = r;
    this.col = col; // color.

  }
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-1, 1);
    this.y = this.y + random(-1, 1)
  } // this would not work without the "this."
  // move () declare a functionality, what it means for a bubble to move.

  edge() { // create the bouncing function.

    if (this.x < 0) {
      this.x = this.x + random(20, 30)
    };
    if (this.x > width) {
      this.x = this.x + random(-30, 20)
    };
    if (this.y < 0) {
      this.y = this.y + random(20, 30)
    };
    if (this.y > height) {
      this.y = this.y + random(-30, 20)
    };

  }

  clicked(px, py) {
    if (dist(this.x, this.y, px, py) < this.r) {
      console.log('youclicked on bubble');
      this.col = random(0, 255);
      this.show() {
        noStroke();
        fill(this.col, 20, 100 + this.col);
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2, this.r)
      }
    }

  }

  show() { //design attribute.
    noStroke();
    fill(this.col, 20, 100 + this.col);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2)
  }
}
```

Basically in the clicked() method I would like that it changes the show() method. Ellipse => Rect when clicked on bubble.

Thanks for your help!

have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, just to be clear, this is not valid javascript syntax (or at least not meaningful anyway):

```
      this.show() {
        noStroke();
        fill(this.col, 20, 100 + this.col);
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2, this.r);
      }
```

In theory you could replace the show method like this:

```
      // Inside the clicked() function
      this.show = function() {
        noStroke();
        fill(this.col, 20, 100 + this.col);
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2, this.r)
      }
```

But that would be a pretty unconventional approach. A more idiomatic approach would be to have a property indicating that the bubble had been clicked and check that property in the show function:

```
  clicked(px, py) {
    if (dist(this.x, this.y, px, py) < this.r) {
      console.log('youclicked on bubble');
      this.col = random(0, 255);

      // Set a property when the click occurs
      this.hasBeenClicked = true;
    }
  }

  show() { //design attribute.
    noStroke();
    fill(this.col, 20, 100 + this.col);

    // Check the property in the show function
    if (this.hasBeenClicked) {
      rect(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2, this.r);
    } else {
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very  much ! Very clear answer!